# White pcolor introduces white bar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following script

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(24,7)
heatmap = plt.pcolor(data)
plt.show()
```

Which results into this image

[image]

How can I remove the white bar at the very top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to manually set the x and y limits sometimes when you're using pcolor.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(24,7)
heatmap = plt.pcolor(data)
plt.ylim(0, 24)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming here that your matrix is not a jagged matrix:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(24,7)
nrow, ncol = data.shape
heatmap = plt.pcolor(data)
# put the major ticks
heatmap.axes.set_xticks(np.arange(ncol), minor=False)
heatmap.axes.set_yticks(np.arange(nrow), minor=False)
heatmap.axes.set_xlim(0,ncol) # Assuming a non jagged matrix
heatmap.axes.set_ylim(0,nrow)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: you can also do `nrow, ncol = data.shape`

Comment: You are right, I prefer this as it is also usable with lists of lists.

Comment: internally mpl is going to convert everything to arrays so you might as well do that as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just simple change. `np.random.rand(24,7)` replace to `np.random.rand(25,7)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(25,7)
heatmap = plt.pcolor(data)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Or add axis Like **plt.axis([0,7,0,24])**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(24,7)
heatmap = plt.pcolor(data)
plt.axis([0,7,0,24])
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]